# Can't connect Jenkins to IBM Websphere 8.5

Tags: jenkins, connection, websphere

I have been using Java 8 and Jenkins 2.346.3 for the deployment. I have installed the WebSphere Deployer plugin 1.6.1 and have copied jar files com.ibm.ws.admin.client_8.5.jar, com.ibm.ws.orb_*.jar and com.ibm.ws.webservices.thinclient_8.5.jar to /websphere-deployer/WEB-INF/lib but when I click Test Connection I get the Following Error. I am trying to connect on my local and port host for SOAP is 8880.

[image: These are the configurations for my websphere]

I have tried everything and all the possible configurations mentioned in the WebSphere Deployer Documentation but couldn't connect. [https://plugins.jenkins.io/websphere-deployer/](https://stackoverflow.com)

Comment: You need to look in the logs to see the details of the error.

Comment: In jenkins.out.log file I get [03/16/23 17:24:26] SSH Launch of QA_Node on https://my_ip:my_port/ibm/console/login.do failed in 165,126 ms. and I can open this ibm console only on Internet Explorer because it doesn't run on other browsers.

Comment: In that case your browsers are messed up as console runs on any browser, but you have to use the correct port and it is not the soap port

Comment: This is the port Information of my profile.

Administrative console port: 9060
Administrative console secure port: 9043
HTTP transport port: 9080
HTTPS transport port: 9443
Bootstrap port: 2809
SOAP connector port: 8880